# Sql Server Replication - Modify Statement Delivery Stored Procedures before the replication starts

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I want to create a subscriber (replica) where fields like `Username`, `Email`, and other personal customer info is masked (I'm creating a replica of production to help developers troubleshoot issues).

So I know that I should modify the `sp_MSins_...` and `sp_MSupd_...` procedures. But the problem is that these procedures exist in the subscriber (right?) so whenever I modify them and then reinitialize the replication to apply their logic to the existing data, the procedures get reverted to their initial state.

I couldn't find anything online about how to handle this.
What are my options?

Comment: Why not masking the data also at the suscriber side? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-ver15 
This way you should not have the overhead of modify the SPs for replication.

Comment: @dbamex I was thinking about it but I prefer to not have production data in that replica at all. that way I have less to worry about securing it.

Answer (score 2):

From docs:

> **Default and custom stored procedures**
>
> The three procedures that
>   replication creates by default for each table article are:
>
> sp_MSins_< tablename >, which handles inserts.
>
> sp_MSupd_< tablename >, which handles updates.
>
> sp_MSdel_< tablename >, which handles deletes.
>
> The  used in the procedure depends on how the article was
>   added to the publication and whether the subscription database
>   contains a table of the same name with a different owner.
>
> Any of these procedures can be replaced with a custom procedure that
>   you specify when adding an article to a publication. Custom procedures
>   are used if an application requires custom logic, such as inserting
>   data into an audit table when a row is updated at a Subscriber. For
>   more information about specifying custom stored procedures, see the
>   how to topics listed above.

[Default and custom stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-articles-specify-how-changes-are-propagated?view=sql-server-ver15#default-and-custom-stored-procedures)

So you create the custom stored procedures in the subscriber database and configure the article to use them in [sp_addarticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).